# Option for deleting UICollectionViewCell on longpress of anUIImageView placed inside it

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Scenario:
I have a programatically created UICollectionView with flow layout inside which a cell contains a UIImageView and a UILabel on it.Now,On Long pressing on UIImageView,a cross image should comes on top right of the UIImageView and on tappig on it, The entire cell should be deleted.I have done some research on this.But it will me more helpul if someone share their ideas ...

Comment: It sounds like you have everything thought up, all you need to do is implement it with the help of some gesture recognizers!

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a tapGestureRecognizer to the UIImageView
2. set the tapGestureRecognizer tag equal to indexPath.row so that you can determine the cell thats need to updated and deleted